# Can't map through data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to map the API data. Can you pls help?

[image: My Code]

[image: Api data from console]

[image: Error]

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: The response from your API is an object and not an array :) ..
So you may loop using keys mapping, for the object.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

My bad, props inside the object are only numbers, so you will need to use Object.keys to loop the object

```
Object.keys(totalCases).map(item=> <div>{totalCases[item]}</div>)
```

———————————————————

totalCases is an object not an array, you can map any of the arrays inside that object though

```
totalCases.cases.map()
```

Answer (score 0):

mapping does not work like that when you are returning an html tag, try this one:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' 

{React.Children.map(totalCases, (data, index) => (
              <li>{data}</li>
 ))}
```